# select particular slide in flex slider angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, flexslider

Using flex slider for angular, but want to select a particular slide based on element click outside flex ng-repeat. There are two methods given by author i.e.
addRandomSlide  and removeRandomSlide but not  to select particular slide. In jquery its easy but for angular yet to find solution.

This is html code...

```
<flex-slider
    slide="s in slideshow.slides track by $index"
    animation="slide" >
    <li >
        <img ng-src="{{s}}">
    </li>
</flex-slider>
```

This is javascript code...

```
$scope.slideshow.slides = [
            'images/mobile/banners/banner1.png',
            'images/mobile/banners/banner2.png',
            'images/mobile/banners/banner-5.png',
            'images/mobile/banners/banner-6.png'
        ];
        $scope.addRandomSlide = function () {
            $scope.slideshow.slides.push('http://lorempixel.com/704/444/cats');
        };
        $scope.removeRandomSlide = function () {

            $scope.slideshow.slides.shift();


        };
```

Comment: there is a thumbnail selection within ng-repeat. `<li data-thumb="{{s}}">`